# Powershell New-ADUser issue with -AccountPassword

Tags: powershell, dns

I am trying to add a list of new students (From a CSV file),
It work fine beside for when I want to add -AccountPassword.

This is the script (Powershell) with -AccountPassword in it:

the script take a really long time to process for each student and the error message I get is: *This operation returned because the timeout period expired*

The user is still created but -Enabled and -ChangePasswordAtLogon is still set to $false despite that I put it to $true

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\userslist.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{  
    $OU = "OU=NewAccts,OU=Students,OU=****,DC=***,DC=com"  
    $Password = $User.password
    $Detailedname = $User.firstname + " " + $User.name
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname 
    $AccountName = $User.AccountName
    $SAM =  $AccountName + 21
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Description = $User.Description
    $Email = $User.Email
       
    New-AdUser -Name $Detailedname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $SAM -DisplayName $Detailedname -GivenName $user.firstname -Surname $user.name -Office $Office -Description $Description -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Test123PWD" -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $True -Email $Email -Path $OU
}
```

Here is when I remove  -AccountPassword and put instead -PasswordNotrequired $true

Everything work fine so this is how I know that my error message come from -AccountPassword

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\userslist.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{  
    $OU = "OU=NewAccts,OU=Students,OU=****,DC=***,DC=com"  
    $Password = $User.password
    $Detailedname = $User.firstname + " " + $User.name
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname 
    $AccountName = $User.AccountName
    $SAM =  $AccountName + 21
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Description = $User.Description
    $Email = $User.Email
   
    New-AdUser -Name $Detailedname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $SAM -DisplayName $Detailedname -GivenName $user.firstname -Surname $user.name -Office $Office -Description $Description -PasswordNotRequired $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $True -Email $Email -Path $OU
}
```

How do I resolve this, since I would like to put a default password for the new students

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **strongly** advise you to start using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters.
Probably, the `password` field in the userslist.csv is empty for some users. In that case it is either an omission in the CSV, or intended so for that user a password is not required.
If you try to set an AccountPassword with aan empty string, you will receive an error.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser):

> User accounts, by default, are created without a password. If you
> provide a password, an attempt will be made to set that password
> however, this can fail due to password policy restrictions. The user
> account will still be created and you may use Set-ADAccountPassword to
> set the password on that account. In order to ensure that accounts
> remain secure, user accounts will never be enabled unless a valid
> password is set or PasswordNotRequired is set to $True.

Question to you is: What is meant by `$SAM =  $AccountName + 21` ??

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\userslist.csv"  | ForEach-Object {
    $fullName = ('{0} {1}' -f $_.firstname, $_.name).Trim()
    $userParams = @{
        Name                  = $fullName
        SamAccountName        = '{0}21' -f $_.AccountName  # 21 is the year the sudent starts
        UserPrincipalName     = $_.Email   # or construct this: "$($_.AccountName)@yourcompany.com"
        DisplayName           = $fullName
        GivenName             = $_.firstname
        Surname               = $_.name
        Office                = $_.Office
        Description           = $_.Description
        Enabled               = $true
        Email                 = $_.Email
        Path                  = "OU=NewAccts,OU=Students,OU=****,DC=***,DC=com"
    }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.password)) {
        # no password for this user in the CSV
        $userParams['ChangePasswordAtLogon'] = $false
        $userParams['PasswordNotRequired']   = $true
    }
    else {
        $userParams['AccountPassword']       = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force
        $userParams['ChangePasswordAtLogon'] = $true
    }

    New-ADUser @userParams
}
```

Comment: the 21 means the year the student are starting! Also I did check my domain password restriction and the default password set to ALL user (no empty ones) does match the domain password restriction. Thank you for you response

Comment: @Maude Then, does that mean my code works for you? If so  please consider marking to his we question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: @Maude P.S> I've edited the '21' in on the SamAccountName.